# how to remove markers from openlayer?

Tags: openlayers

I added some markers to the open layer map. I want to know how I can remove everything from the map when I click on a button. I found a way to do that but it needs multiple click and that's awful.

I use the code below to remove:

```js
function ClMap() {
            map.getLayers().forEach(function (layer) {
                if (layer.P.name != "Main" && layer.P.name != "GIS") {
                    map.removeLayer(layer);
                }

                map.removeInteraction(draw);
            });
            ol.Observable.unByKey(keyClick);
        }
```

Comment: yr code is using an iterator over the layer collection, and removing it based on validation.. what specific change do you want to have here

Comment: I want to remove markers from the map.the if clause there , is for not removing the map @NitinSingh

Comment: Can't you just clear the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
                var layersToRemove = [];

            map.getLayers().forEach(function (layer) {
                if (layer.P.name == "popupMarker") {
                    //map.removeLayer(layer);
                    layersToRemove.push(layer);
                }
                map.removeInteraction(draw);
            });
            var len = layersToRemove.length;
            for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                map.removeLayer(layersToRemove[i]);
            }
            ol.Observable.unByKey(keyClick);
```